# How can I type half-space in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

When I press "Shift + Space" to type half-space (when I 'm writing in Persian) in a RichTextBox, it just inserts space. It types all other Persian characters correctly, but when it comes to "Shift+Space", it types just space.

The name of this character is "ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER" and the information is given in this link: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm.

I should mention that I fixed the problem by handling previewKewDown event; but I like to know what is the problem with this key combination in a RichTextBox.

thanks.

Comment: have you tried changing the culture of rich text box?

Comment: @D J. thanks, but I don't think the problem is with the language or culture

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same in a TextBox.

Comment: @Ron, why don't you think the problem is with the language or culture? Treating Shift+Space as ZWNJ is not a standard Windows behavior. By default, Shift+Space is just space. If you're seeing it treated as ZWNJ elsewhere, it's because of *some* kind of locale setting. (Or you're just comparing to another app that intercepts the key, the way you've done in your PreviewKeyDown.)

Comment: @JoeWhite, you are right, it is because of a locale setting. I've installed `Iranian Standard Persian Keyboard` (http://persian-computing.org/en/Main_Page). Everything is fine in `Windows Notepad` and other applications in windows, but when it comes to my projects, it just types space. In fact I'm not sure that the problem is not with culture.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this functionality would need to be programmed as a part of the control (either the RichTextBox or some inherited class), but it appears that this is not the case.

One alternative I found on [another website](http://sartre2.byu.edu/persian/persianword/zwnj.htm) was to press `Alt + 0157` *(use the keypad with NumLock enabled to enter each digit, one at a time)*, although this isn't as good as your solution of overriding the `previewKewDown` event.

[image: Symbol Screen]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simply with your keyboard layout in windows. Windows' keyboard layout for Persian simply does not support ZWNJ. If you use *Iranian Standard Persian Keyboard (ISIRI 9147) (Version 2.0)*  from [Persian Computing Community Site](http://persian-computing.org/en/Main_Page), it will be available.

Comment: Thanks, but I 'm using this layout

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with the very same issue and fixed the problem in code-behind by handling the `PreviewKeyDown` event.
Just wanted to add that my little research on the matter made me thinking that the `xml:space` attribute on the underlying `Run` element can be the cause of the issue.
Read about how whitespace is processed in XAML [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746.aspx).